# Extracting values from an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML file that's in the following form,

```
<Mapping name="abc">
  <Attribute name="a1" value="a2" />
  <Attribute name="..." value="..." />
</Mapping>
```

I want to extract all pairs of `Attribute` names and values where the `Mapping` name is `"abc"` (it occurs in multiple parts of the file).  How can I do this?

Comment: Any particular way you need to read the Xml?  XmlReader?  XmlDocument?  etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and a XPath expression seems like a very easy way to achieve this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var values = doc.XPathSelectElements("//Mapping[@name='abc']");
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            foreach (var att in item.Elements("Attribute"))
            {
                var name = att.Attribute("name").Value;
                var value = att.Attribute("value").Value;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", name, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or a [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) if the XML document is very large and cannot fit into memory:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
        {
            bool reading = false;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Mapping")
                {
                    var name = reader.GetAttribute("name");
                    reading = name == "abc";
                }

                if (reading && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Attribute")
                {
                    var name = reader.GetAttribute("name");
                    var value = reader.GetAttribute("value");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", name, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He actually only wants the names and values under the `Mapping`'s that have that particular name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried the first solution, there is no output at all. Tried replacing //Attribute with //Mapping but I got NullPointerException

Comment: @Jeff Mercado, @Bo Tian, you are correct, I didn't read the question and the actual XML structure carefully. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to XML for this.

```
var items = from item in purchaseOrder.Descendants("Mapping")
            where (string) item.Attribute("name") == "abc"
            select new
            {
                Name = (string) item.Element("name"),
                Value = (string) item.Element("value")
            };
```

Comment: syntax error. can't resolve symbol select, and if I were to remove the semicolon on the second line, the compiler says can't resolve symbol item

Comment: @Bo Tian, you're probably missing the System.Xml.Linq reference

Comment: I didn't. I have "using System.Xml.Linq" at the start of the source code

Comment: The syntax was all wrong (VB.NET LINQ and C# LINQ are not interchangeable ;)).  I corrected it and the syntax should be fine now.  (though there is a different problem with the code which I did not correct)